# Returning array in C, Sudoku Solver

Tags: c

So I'm creating a sudoku solver in C. Here's my full code as of now, I've mostly been using python and just got into C, I basically converted a lot of python functions to C to get this but I think it'll work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_empty();
int possible_v();
int solver();

int main(){
    int s_array[9][9];
    FILE * fpointer;
    int i;
    int j;

    fpointer = fopen("sudoku001.txt", "r");

    for (i=0; i<9; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<9; j++){
            fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &s_array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            printf("------------------------------\n");
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", s_array[i][j]);
            if ((j + 1) % 3 == 0) {
                printf("|");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



    solver(s_array);

    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            printf("------------------------------\n");
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", s_array[i][j]);
            if ((j + 1) % 3 == 0) {
                printf("|");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;


}

int is_empty(int board[9][9]){
    int i;
    int j;
    int is_empty= 0;
    for (i=0; i<9; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<9; j++){
            if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                is_empty = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_empty == 1){
            break;
        }
    }
    return is_empty;
}

int possible_v(int board[9][9], int i, int j) {
    int p_array[9] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int x;
    int y;
    int temp;

    for (x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        if (board[x][j] != 0) {
            temp = board[x][j];
            p_array[temp - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    for (y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        if (board[i][y] != 0) {
            temp = board[i][y];
            p_array[temp - 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    int m;
    int n;
    int temp1;
    int temp2;
    if (i>= 0 && i <= 2) {
        m = 0;
    }
    else if (i>= 3 && i<=5) {
        m = 3;
    }
    else{
        m = 6;
    }

    if (j>= 0 && j <= 2) {
        n = 0;
    }
    else if (j>= 3 && j<=5) {
        n = 3;
    }
    else{
        n = 6;
    }

    temp1 = m;
    temp2 = n;

    for (temp1; temp1<temp1+3; temp1++){
        for (temp2; temp2<temp2+3; temp2++){
            if (board[temp1][temp2] != 0){
                p_array[board[temp1][temp2]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    temp1 = 1;
    for (temp1; temp1<10){
        if (p_array[temp1] == 0){
            p_array[temp1] = temp1;
        }
        else{
            p_array[temp1] = 0;
        }
    }
    return p_array;
}

int solver(int board[9][9]){
    int i;
    int j;
    int x;
    int y;
    int empty_check;
    int p_values;
    int temp;

    if (is_empty(board) == 0){
       printf("Board Completed");
       empty_check = 0;
       return empty_check;
    }
    else{
        for (x = 0; x < 9; x++){
            for (y = 0; y< 9; y++){
                if (board[x][y] == 0){
                    i = x;
                    j = y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        p_values = possible_v(board, i, j);

        for (temp = 1; temp <10; temp++){
            if (p_values[temp] != 0){
                board[i][j] = p_values[temp];
                solver(board);
            }
        }
        board[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

My main issue when compiling is getting the last two functions work with each other.

Function 'solver' calls and binds function 'possible_v'. Possible_V returns an array which I need to solve the puzzle. How can I make this work? .

Comment: Make it `int *possible_v()`. You can then use the returned pointer as an array.

Comment: @torstenvl: Not if it’s a pointer to an array, like `p_array` here, that is local to the function…

Comment: C doesn't allow a function to return an array — (C11 §6.5.2.2 Function calls ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p1): _The expression that denotes the called function… shall have type pointer to function returning `void` or returning a complete object type other than an array type._  So you can't simply return an array.  You could allocate memory in the called function and return a pointer to the calling function which would have to ensure it is freed appropriately, or the calling function can pass an array to the called function and the called function sets the array's value.

Comment: @DavisHerring has a good point. Since you're allocating `p_array` on the stack here ("automatic storage" in the language of the Standard), the pointer will no longer point to valid memory when the function returns. You should allocate space for `p_array` with `malloc()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have the array locally declared, hence it cannot be passed back since it is destroyed once the function is exited. The workaround to this is to dynamically declare the array using malloc `int *parray = (int*)malloc(9*sizeof(int));` and using the return type `int*` instead of `int`. But do not forget to free the allocated memory, else you will just keep allocating new memory from heap for every call you make.

As a side note, your implementation of Sudoku solver is a bit complex, and there is no need to return an array. You need to pass only the board. Here is an implementation of Sudoku Solver. This works both for 9x9 and 6X6 boards.

**Edit** : As advised by David Rankin, I have converted the C++ code to C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int n;

int issafe(int **board,int i,int j,int num){

  for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    if(board[i][k] == num || board[k][j] == num)
     return 0;

  int cellx,celly;
  if(n==6){

   cellx = (i/2)*2;
   celly = (j/3)*3;

   for(int l=cellx;l<cellx+2;l++)
     for(int m=celly;m<celly+3;m++)
      if(board[l][m] == num){
        return 0;
      }

   return 1;
 }

 int root = sqrt(n);
 cellx = (i/(root))*root;
 celly = (j/(root))*root;

 for(int l=cellx;l<cellx+root;l++)
  for(int m=celly;m<celly+root;m++)
    if(board[l][m] == num)
     return 0;

 return 1;
}

int solve(int **board,int i,int j){

  if(i == n)
    return 1;

  if(j == n){
    return solve(board,i+1,0);
  }

  if(board[i][j] != 0)
    return solve(board,i,j+1);

  for(int k=1;k<n+1;k++)
    if(issafe(board,i,j,k)){
      board[i][j] = k;
      if(solve(board,i,j+1))
        return 1;
      //backtrack
      board[i][j] = 0;
    }

  return 0;
}

int main(){

  do{
    printf("Enter size of board(9 or 6): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  }while(n != 9 && n != 6);

  int **board;
  board = malloc(sizeof *board * n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    board[i] = malloc(sizeof *board * n);

  // input
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      scanf("%d",&board[i][j]);

  if(solve(board,0,0))
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("%d ",board[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No ding since you are still relatively new, but your 1st paragraph addresses the question, everything from paragraph 2 through the end attempts to answer a C question by providing a C++ solution. They are two different languages. However, to your credit, the C++ code only differs in the use of `new` verses `malloc` and `iostream` instead of `stdio.h`. In these cases, it would be better to make the changes and provide an improved C solution rather than posting C++ code in answer to a C question.

Comment: You are right @DavidC.Rankin. I have made the required changes in the code.

Comment: Much better. One nit and one significant invitation for *Undefined Behavior*. (1-nit) See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) (2-invitiation for UB) You must **always** validate the **return** of `scanf` to have any confidence you have received valid input. What happens in your code if the user slips and types `'r'` instead of `5`? (you may also want to update the wording in paragraph 2 `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I got to learn a lot of new things from that comment.                
(1) meaning of nit (2) casting of malloc (3) not using brackets with sizeof in this case. Thanks a lot for these insights :)

Comment: Sure, glad to help. That's what we are here for.